# Выбор только нужных полей в `GridView`

Tags: php, yii2

С помощью `CRUD` сгенериовал `GridView`.
В моем случае в таблице в БД много столбцов, поэтому чтоб страница не затянулось по ширине, Я прописал адаптивные стили для таблиц.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-responsive'],
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'col_1',
            'col_2',
            'col_3',
            ...
            'col_30',
            'col_31',     
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],   
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

В итоге немного неудобно получается работать прокручивая на лево на право.

Поэтому хотел спросить есть ли вожможность Выбора нужных полей, и сформировать таблицу с помощью группы чекбоксов например

Comment: не очень понятно что вы имеете в виду, напишите пример того что вы хотите получить.

Comment: @fens Например до таблицы `GridView` показать список всех полей (столбцов) и рядом у каждого свой чекбоксом для выбора.
Пользователь мог выбрать нужные ему поля(столбцы) и нажать кнопку допустим `сформировать таблицу`.
И `Gridview` сгенерирует таблицу со столбцами которых выбрал пользователь. Надеюсь смог объяснить

Comment: Так а что вам мешает это сделать, набор полей которые надо показывать это обычный массив, сделайте форму до GridView с списком всех столбцов, и чекбоксов к ним, и отправляете формой, в итоге на стороне сервера вы получите массив с колонками которые потом прокинете в GridView.

Comment: @fens в принципе понятно, но может уже есть готовое решение для подобных задач

Comment: @Xfirab видел один такой грид, можете почерпнуть оттуда идею: https://github.com/bupy7/yii2-grid